# Is it possible to offer different shipping methods to customers in different locations

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

We ship perishable goods and currently get exact price quotes from UPS and USPS and allow the customer to choose their shipping method  (ground, 2nd day, etc.).  During the summer months we have to restrict the available shipping methods to 2nd Day air or better to ensure our goods are in good shape when they arrive.
  We would like to be able to offer ground shipping to the people who live nearby, while still only offering 2nd day or better to people who live further away.  We still want to use the exact price quotes so I'm pretty sure table rates won't work, and I haven't been able to figure out another way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Tyler have you check this free extension? http://webshopapps.com/ca/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

In some of my project with the free module option was enough.

Best,
ALe.